# Bitcore wallet service : Unable to connect with 3232

Tags: php, bitcoin, bitcore

I am trying to connect bitcore wallet service to my bit core-lib but it give me error as below:

```
Unable to connect

    Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:3232.

        The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
        If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
        If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

One more thing is BWS is installed successfully also configure with 3232 port with below code :

```
"bitcore-wallet-service":{
     "bwsPort":3232
    }
```

Comment: You checked its running, and listening on that port `netstat -pant | grep 3232`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone : yes, it'll give me like tcp6       0      0 :::3232                 :::*                    LISTEN      5362/bitcored but when i try into browser it'll not work

Comment: @Codebrekers
Love from India.
Can you tell me where can I get the best documents and examples to learn about the blockchain?